Dict type variable on non generic class methods
On the following code:
from typing import Generic
from typing import TypeVar
from typing import reveal_type


T = TypeVar('T')


class Field(Generic[T]):
    """A field definition with a default value."""

    def __init__(self, default_value: T):
        self.default_value = default_value


class FieldDataCollection:
    """A collection of field values."""

    def __init__(self, value_per_field: dict[Field[T], T]) -> None:
        self._value_per_field = value_per_field

    def get_field_value(self, field: Field[T]) -> T:
        """Return the field value if in the collection or the field default value."""
        return self._value_per_field.get(field, field.default_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Field(1)
    value = FieldDataCollection({foo: 2}).get_field_value(foo)
    reveal_type(value)


I get the following errors from mypy with 1.11.0 (but not with previous versions) running in strict mode:
error: Incompatible return value type (got "T@__init__", expected "T@get_field_value")  [return-value]
error: Argument 1 to "get" of "dict" has incompatible type "Field[T@get_field_value]"; expected "Field[T@__init__]"  [arg-type]
error: Argument 2 to "get" of "dict" has incompatible type "T@get_field_value"; expected "T@__init__"  [arg-type]
note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"

From what I understand of these errors mypy complains that the type inferred in the __init__ method is somehow different from the type in the get_field_value method.
I tried to use a different type variable for the get_field_value:
T = TypeVar("T")
Tfield = TypeVar("Tfield")

...

class FieldDataCollection:
    ...

    def get_field_value(self, field: Field[Tfield]) -> Tfield:
        ...

But mypy seems to catch the difference and complains in the same fashion:
error: Incompatible return value type (got "T", expected "Tfield")  [return-value]
error: Argument 1 to "get" of "dict" has incompatible type "Field[Tfield]"; expected "Field[T]"  [arg-type]
error: Argument 2 to "get" of "dict" has incompatible type "Tfield"; expected "T"  [arg-type]
note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"

I tried using Mapping or MutableMapping instead of dict which works fine but then I cannot use methods of dict like copy.
Do you think it is a regression on mypy side?
Otherwise, do you have any idea on how to annotate the FieldDataCollection class properly?

I think you should make FieldDataCollection generic as well. Currently the class is not generic, only the method is. The first error complains about the T from the init not necessarily being the same T as in your get method, because both methods have independent T since the class is not itself generic in T.

@luk2302 Please post that as an answer.

@luk2302 Thank you for you reply. Making FieldDataCollection generic over T is not the behavior I am looking for because it will limit the kind of Field I can insert into the dictionary. Potentially, one could insert Field[str] or Field[int].

You want to be able to insert multiple different Field variants? At that point you can no longer use any kind of type safety and you need to basically explicitly ignore the mypy compaints because mypy is right: the types are not compatible and there is no way to make them compatible. When you use FieldDataCollection({foo: 2}) you effectively produce a dict[Field[int], int] and then you try to access it using a (potentially different) Field[T]. I am not sure about the terminology here, but T in your dict can only have one specific value, it cannot be both str and int.

Something like {foo: 2, Field("x"): "y"} would bind T to object, the most specific common superclass of int and str. Neither entry would type check in that case, because dict is invariant. (Changing dict to typing.Mapping would fix that, but still leave the problem of T being too general.)

Related: How to add type hints for a dictionary that maps a class to an instance of that class?.

This seems to actually be a scoping issue, the type T in FieldDataCollection is not defined, so the interpretation is different, and in this case not the interpretation you were looking for. Adding Generic[T] to FieldDataCollection resolves this for mypy version 1.11.0, as it ensures the type used in __init__ must be the same as that used in get_field_value.
Also, as specified in the comments, to ensure both Field[str] and Field[int] can be used in FieldDataCollection we must make T covariant:
from typing import Generic
from typing import TypeVar
from typing import reveal_type


T = TypeVar('T', covariant=True)


class Field(Generic[T]):
    """A field definition with a default value."""

    def __init__(self, default_value: T):
        self.default_value = default_value


class FieldDataCollection(Generic[T]):
    """A collection of field values."""

    def __init__(self, value_per_field: dict[Field[T], T]) -> None:
        self._value_per_field = value_per_field

    def get_field_value(self, field: Field[T]) -> T:
        """Return the field value if in the collection or the field default value."""
        return self._value_per_field.get(field, field.default_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Field(1)
    foo_str  = Field("test")
    value = FieldDataCollection({foo: 2, foo_str: "v"}).get_field_value(foo)
    reveal_type(value)

Hope this helps!
Update: On reviewing the earlier comments, I've expanded it to allow for the multiple key types.

Ah apologies, I've just realised the comments section on the earlier post discusses this - I'll revise if needed.

This is great! Thank you very much for the tip.
How would you deal with a set_field_value(self, field: Field[T], value: T) -> None ?
It seems covariant variables cannot be used as parameter.

As mentioned in the comments T becomes object in this case because that is the common super type of str and int. See the output of reveal_type of value or the FieldDataCollection itself. Therefore the generic is basically useless now.

@luk2302 in Pyright at least the reveal_type shows int | str, wondering if maybe it works differently in mypy? @PoloB I'll have a think re set_field_value

@Mark well, obviously that is also a valid type inference. But one that is equally useless because which one is value now, an int or a str? object or a union of all possible types means you don't know the type.

int | str is still much more specific than object - I would argue this is the best you can determine, unless you use a TypedDict to represent the dict object. dict in its standard formulation has to have one type to represent the keys, and in the above the key type is Field[int | str].
